# How to generate a radio group with a sorted data source?

Tags: java, radio-button, struts2

```
<s:sort comparator="varDataComparator" source="#var.varDatas" var="datas">
</s:sort>
<s:radio list="${pageContext.datas}" listKey="value" listValue="value" id="vardataId" name="%{#var.varId}"></s:radio>
```

I want to make a radio group with sorted `#var.varDatas` as source value, but `s:radio` *list* attribute doesn't accept any expressions. So what should I do?

Thx.

**PS**:
I found a solution:

```
<s:sort comparator="varDataComparator" source="#var.varDatas" var="datas">
  <s:set var="temp"></s:set>
  <s:radio list="#temp" listKey="value" listValue="value" id="vardataId" name="%{#var.varId}"/>
</s:sort>
```

here I don't assign any value to *temp* variable in *set* tag, but it actually shows all sorted data in my jsp, maybe the default value is just the top element value of the *value stack*, I am not sure of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<s:sort comparator="varDataComparator" source="#var.varDatas" var="datas">
  <s:set var="temp"></s:set>
  <s:radio list="#temp" listKey="value" listValue="value" id="vardataId" name="%{#var.varId}"/>
</s:sort>
```